# Error plotting 2 data sets in R using ggplot and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am trying to create a plot in R using the packages GGPlot and Plotly. However, for this data set my PCE values are much smaller than my COV values.

[Table of PCE and COV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl22n.png)

[Picture of Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Ed2.png)

As you can see in the picture, my PCE values are being suppressed into a straight line because my COV values are much larger. How can I plot both PCE and COV together in a way that the PCE plot does not get suppressed? This is my code:

```
test <- ggplot(zz, aes(x=month,y = value, group=variable, color=variable)) + xlab("Date") +  ylab("PCE") + theme_minimal(base_size = 14, base_family = "Georgia") + geom_point() + geom_line() 

testinteractive <- ggplotly(test)

testinteractive
```

Comment: ggplot does not officially support dual axes.  You can add `facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_y")`

Comment: @DanSlone, there is support for dual axes via the `sec_axis` argument, [used in conjunction with a position scale function](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html).  It's an option if you really need two lines on the same space, where the y values differ by orders of magnitude.  It basically multiplies the one value by a factor and uses that for plotting, while labelling the axis based on the values before transformation.  Faceting is the other, preferred option, but it's ultimately up to the OP.  If you want specific help, please post your data (not as an image).

Comment: @chemdork123 hey thanks!  That marks a big change from the earlier philosophy.  I've had to script so many workarounds.

Comment: Haven't used `sec_axis` much in my work.. and still very much not recommended.  I feel it was begrudgingly added by the team on request.  Definitely not really in the philosophy of grammar of graphics, for sure.

Comment: @chemdork123 Yep I understand and agree with that philosophy.  Sometimes it's nice to have annotations labeled on the other axis without having to kluge it in.